# Alamofire not working well with swift 3

Tags: swift, alamofire, cocoapods-1.1.1

I have a project written by swift 2.
I updated to swift 3, I'm using [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#http-methods) and [swiftyjson](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON)
so I updated their by cocoapods and I fixed all my project issues,
after all that I got this error about `Alamofire`

```
The following binaries use incompatible versions of Swift:
```

[image]

also I have these warnings

[image]

this is my pod file 
[image]

this what I see in terminal after `pod update`

```
Update all pods
Updating local specs repositories

CocoaPods 1.2.0.beta.1 is available.
To update use: `sudo gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information, see https://blog.cocoapods.org and the CHANGELOG for this version at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/releases/tag/1.2.0.beta.1

Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Alamofire (4.0.1)
Using DropDown (2)
Using SideMenu (2.0.5)
Using SwiftyJSON (3.1.1)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 4 dependencies from the Podfile and 4 total pods installed.

[!] The `ehtamiApp [Debug]` target overrides the `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ehtamiApp/Pods-ehtamiApp.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The `ehtamiApp [Release]` target overrides the `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-ehtamiApp/Pods-ehtamiApp.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

what is that mean? and how I can fix it?

Comment: Try cleaning out intermediate build files with cmd+shift+k or by going to product > clean

Comment: @AlanPerez I did it and it's tell me "clean succeeded" but when I run it the error back again and tell me "Build Failed"

Comment: @AlanPerez I add new photo in QA

Comment: you have to update your pods to newer versions as well. Alamofire should be migrated to version 4.

Comment: @nyekimov I deleted Alamofire and installed again by pod and update my Alamofire code to new sentences, Is that correct? or what I should do?

Comment: @joda paste here the contents of your Podfile. We will see if you have to change that or not and you can try run 'pod update' command as well.

Comment: Yay, looks like the Alamofire is on a different version of Swift, could you post your pod file?

Comment: @nyekimov I tried to use "pod update" and after it I open the project again but it's ask me to convert the code to swift 3!!!!!! why it's do that? I edited the code to swift 3 and I re-installed all pods

Comment: @YuchenZhong I updated my QA

Comment: @nyekimov I updated my QA

Comment: Could you show your console output after pod update?

Comment: BTW, it is not very good to upload images. Plain text is better. Images are not searchable by other people, and thus not helpful to the community.

Comment: Also, what is your cocoa pod version?

Comment: @YuchenZhong How I can know my pod version or update it? I add what I see after update

Comment: You can type `pod --version`

Comment: @YuchenZhong its `1.1.1`

Comment: Hmm, I am out of suggestions. It seems that you have warnings installing the pods, but I don't know what they are about. Sorry about that ..

Comment: @YuchenZhong ohh :( , ok can I contact by email and let you access to my computer by TeamViewer or something to try do anything with this, please :( ?

Comment: Sorry, @joda, not that I don't want to, I cannot do anything else other than just type command + shift + k for you, which you've already tried...

Comment: I also migrated from swift 2 Alamofire to swift 3 and it's working normally but I'm using Carthage.

Comment: @CleverAlmeida How I use Carthage? Is it work with it?

Comment: @joda, It's simpler than CocoaPods. Download and run the Carthage.pkg file for the latest release: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage/releases, create a file with name "Carthage" in the root of your project, insert "github "Alamofire/Alamofire" ~> 4.0" in this file and run "carthage update --platform IOS" at the terminal, in the root too. I put "--platform IOS" because I use just IOS but you can change this option. Good Luck !